# How to store and generate a pdf from text fields using javafx

Tags: eclipse, javafx, itext

I created a form where the user fills fields (name, first name, number, date1, date2 and choose between 3 propositions: man, woman, child).
I wish I could store user answers (to put them in a database) and incorporate them into a pdf file.

However I cannot do anything functional for my pdf, how to do it? Do you have any advice or examples?
Should I generate a pdf template before which will be field by user answer? I tried to do something with 'itextpdf' but without success
another strategy?

help me!

here is my code :

data file

```
public class Data {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Integer numb;
    private String date1;
    private String date2;

    public Patient(String name, String surname, Integer numb, String date1, String date2) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.numb = numb;
        this.date1 = date1;
        this.date2 = date2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public Integer getNumb() {
        return numb;
    }

    public String getDate1() {
        return date1;
    }

    public String getDate2() {
        return date2;
    }

}
```

dataManager file

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import main;
import models.data;

public class DataManager {


    private Main main;

    public DataManager(Main main) {
        super();
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void addData(data p) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Data(name, surname, numb, date1, date2) VALUES ("
                + "\"" + p.getName() + "\", "
                + "\"" + p.getSurname() + "\", "
                + "\"" + p.getNumb() + "\", "
                + "\"" + p.getDate1() + "\", "
                + "\"" + p.getDate2() + "\");";
        try {
            this.main.getDatabase().connect();
            this.main.getDatabase().updateValue(query);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            this.main.getDatabase().disconnect();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getData() {
        ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

        String query = "SELECT name, surname, numb, Date1, Date2 FROM Data ORDER BY name";
        try {
            this.main.getDatabase().connect();
            ResultSet rslt = this.main.getDatabase().getResultOf(query.toString());
            while (rslt.next()) {
                data.add(new Data(rslt.getString("name"), rslt.getString("surname"), rslt.getInt("numb"),rslt.getString("Date1"),rslt.getString("Date2")));
            }
            rslt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            this.main.getDatabase().disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

fichier options

```
public class Options {


    public enum Ref {
        man("man"),
        woman("woman"),
        child("child");

        private final String refName;

        Ref(String goalName){
            this.refName = goalName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return refName;
        }
    }
    private Ref ref;

    public Ref getRef() {
        return ref;
    }


}
```

FormController file

```
import Main;
import models.options;



public class FormController{

    Map<String,Ref> refsMap = new HashMap<String,Ref>();

    private Main main;

    private JFrame frame;


    TextArea ta = new TextArea();

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    @FXML
    private TextField tfCharName;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfCharSurname;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfNum;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfDate1;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfDate2;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> cbGoal;

    @FXML
    private Button bChoose;

    @FXML
    private Button bFinish;

    @FXML
    private String eFinish;



    @FXML public void initialize(){

    Ref[] refs = Ref.values();
    for (Ref ref : refs) {
        refsMap.put(ref.toString(), ref);
    }

    cbGoal.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(refsMap.keySet()));

    }

    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Button pressedButton = (Button) event.getSource();

        if(pressedButton==bChoose){
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (selectedFile != null) {



                    try {
                        ta.setText(new String(Files.readAllBytes(selectedFile.toPath())));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {}
            }

        }


        else if(pressedButton==bFinish){

            //fields
            String name = tfCharName.getText().trim();
            String surname = tfCharSurname.getText().trim();
            String numb = tfNum.toString().trim();
            String date1 = tfDate1.getText().trim();
            String date2 = tfDate2.getText().trim();

//                  AddToReport field = new AddToReport (name+" "+surname+" "+number+" "+date1+" "+date2);
//                  AddToReport field = new AddToReport ();
//                  this.dataManager.updateData(new Data(this.name, surname, number, date1, date2));
//                  Button pressedButton = (Button) event.getSource();
                    Stage mainStage = (Stage) pressedButton.getScene().getWindow();
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                     loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("../view/following.fxml"));

                     AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                     Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                     dialogStage.setTitle("suite");
                     dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                     Window primaryStage = null;
                    dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                     Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                     dialogStage.setScene(scene);

                     dialogStage.show();

    }
    }
}
```

form.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.FormController">

   <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="New analysis" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true">
            <font>
                <Font size="29.0" />
            </font>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </Label>
      <ScrollPane>
         <content>
            <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
                <children>
                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                        <children>
                            <Label text="Enter patient name and surname" />
                            <TextField fx:id="tfCharSurname" promptText="Name">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </TextField>
                            <TextField fx:id="tfCharSurname" promptText="Surname" />
                        </children>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>

                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                            <Label text="number" />
                            <TextField fx:id="tfNum" promptText="number">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </TextField>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                            <Label text="date1" />
                            <TextField fx:id="tfDate1" promptText="date1">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </TextField>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                            <Label text="date2" />
                            <TextField fx:id="tfDate2" promptText="date2">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </TextField>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <children>
                            <Label text="Choisir">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Label>
                            <ChoiceBox fx:id="cbGoal" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        </children>
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>
                    <HBox fillHeight="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                <children>
                            <Label text="Choose input file">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Label>
                    <Button fx:id="bChoose" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="choose">
                    </Button>
                        </children>
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </HBox>

                </children>
                <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                </padding>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>

                    <Button fx:id="bFinish" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="suite">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </Button>
      <Label fx:id="eFinish" alignment="CENTER" textFill="#ee0404">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </Label>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **itext** tool for generating pdf's. you should be confident about it.
There are many examples about using itext pdf tool with java programming.

you already have data to show in pdf, Just create a class called GeneratePdf and use it. You just need to give your data to itext paragraph, table, cell whatever you need.

examples in [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/create-pdf-files-in-java-itext-tutorial/).

Comment: That statement is false. As you can read for yourself on the iText website (https://itextpdf.com/agpl), iText can be used at no cost, provided that you follow the terms as set forth in the Free Software License Agreement, in this particular case the Affero General Public License Agreement (AGPL). You only need to pay for iText if you do not want to be bound by the terms of the AGPL.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I use the word 'free' wrong. A lot of people thinks the iText is completed free without any bounds to licenses and tend to use it for commercial uses, that's why i said it's not 'free'. In any case thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So "free" in the sense of "free lunch", but not "free" in the sense of "free speech".

Comment: It depends on who you consider the recipient of the Freedom: the author, or the end user? Licenses like AGPL, GPL etc guarantee that the end user has the same rights as the author. Commercial licenses take away the Freedom from the end user.